# Want to get back in touch with professor so he won't forget me but don't know what to say

Tags: email, academic-life, communication

I want to get back in touch with professor so he won't forget me but don't know what to say! I took a class with him, but that's about it. I would like to keep in touch, so that he will remember me in the future but it's already been a few months, I just have no idea what to say, as I do not have anything to say *really* (Haven't been able to catch up with any research or so due to work). Any advice?

Comment: Can you clarify why is it important to you that he remembers you?

Comment: I would like to do a PhD in 3-4 years and will either need a reference or I would also like studying with him. However, it's all quite unclear as of now and I would like to build the relationship first. I just don't know how to get more on his radar, as it were.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy it when former students let me know what they are working on and how what they learned in my course is assisting them in their career.

I would suggest an email sharing this information and thanking the professor for teaching such a useful course.

Answer (score 1):

Had a very similar situation recently, with an academic I worked with over 15 years ago.

The email I sent was related to his current work (research displayed on his professional website - this is an important 'hook' I found), and also linking it to the research that we collaborated with all that time ago and the classes I took from him earlier still.

After the usual greetings, I firstly asked about about some of his current research that was of interest.  Then in the next paragraph, I wrote a reminder of when we worked together in the context of how I have worked from there (once again linking it to his research). Then wished him well and signed off.

He remembered me - and answered my questions and we are now back in dialogue.